# My pc on windows 10 is woken up randomly. Source: network adapter through Magic Packet

Tags: windows, networking, wake-on-lan

my pc on windows 10 is woken up randomly usually at night. Source: network adapter through Magic Packet. I did disable that option but I'm worrying if it can mean that somebody/something is trying to access my computer from the network for whatever reason.
Is it normal behavior or I have to be careful and watch for some hack attacks or whatever it is that has  bad intention.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have port forwardings set up? They can be used to receive a Magic Packet over the Internet. If you don’t, some device inside your local network is the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try disabling Wake-on-LAN. It's possible that something is malfunctioning, and it's probably nothing to worry about. But at the same time, what's the point of having it active on a personal PC?

[Guide](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/wake-on-lan-windows-8) to enable/disable... in brief: load Device Manager > expand Network Adapters > Double-click the ethernet device > select Advanced tab > under Property select Wake on Magic Packet > change the Value to Disabled.

Comment: Thanks for the reply David.
It was active by default I suppose.
I deactivated it but I was just wondering what kind of data my PC was receiving that it made it wake up and if it still does during my normal use of computer.

Comment: I would be inclined to at least add a précis of the linked instructions - otherwise if the link disappears, this answer becomes void.

Comment: Good call Tetsujin. You're right, Mike, it's active by default. Sorry I guess my answer missed the point a bit - it would be good to see some more insightful suggestions about what exactly could be going on, I'd be very interested.